# Rails Signalling Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, signals, server, message, webrtc

I am creating an app with Ruby on Rails (4.2). I want to add a WebRTC functionality to it so that two users can choose to videochat with each other. I'd appreciate if you can help with:

- What are some of the options to create a signalling server with Rails (I have no Node.js experience)?
- Any video tutorial or sample code for creating a simple signalling server with Rails (and even better for using WebRTC)?

Thanks.

Comment: To the guys who are down-rating the question: please explain why you think it's a bad question and may be edit it.

Comment: You are asking for an offsite tool or tutorial...that is off topic for SO. FYI, I am not one of the ones that have down voted your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for you to implement a signalling server. Run an existing one independent of your rails app.

E.g. if you're using SIP have a look at [Kamailio](http://www.kamailio.org/w/) or [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/]). Or in your case something like [Signalmaster](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster) might be easier.

The signalling "part" of your application will be independent of your rails application.
Except for the client-code which will probably run inside the same page (javascript environment) in your browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and help. Signalmaster sounds great, but do I need to learn about STUN/TURN? I have a simple twitter-like app (https://www.railstutorial.org/) and I want to find the simplest way to add video connection. What would be the easiest option? Is there a book/tutorial that explains integrating a Rails application with WebRTC step by step for a beginner?

Comment: What do you think about Pusher?

Comment: Yeah you need to at least learn about STUN. TURN is probably fine for later. Check out [this book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545) which has a great WebRTC chapter covering this stuff. (I'm not familiar with Pusher sorry)

Comment: np @user2725109 if you need more help just send me an email. (the one on my profile page).